# Gerenics changes parameter from 'a to obj

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

Given this function:

```
let endFlow x = 
    match x with
    | Ok o -> ()
    | Error (e: string) ->
        exn e |> raise
```

x is resolved to be Result<'a, string>.
If i change the function to have a generic parameter for exception type, like this:

```
let endFlow<'T when 'T :> exn> x = 
    match x with
    | Ok o -> ()
    | Error (e: string) ->
        exn e :?> 'T |> raise
```

Now x is resolved to be `Result<obj, string>`.
Can i somehow have generics without the obj constraint for the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you have defined only *one* generic parameter. There is no `'a` to speak of.

Before, when you didn't specify any generic parameters, the compiler was free to invent whatever it needed to properly generalize the code. But now that you explicitly said that your function has exactly one generic parameter `'T`, the compiler can't just barge in and add an `'a` - that would change the signature that you prescribed.

So, let's help the compiler out and add an `'a` parameter:

```
let endFlow<`a, 'T when 'T :> exn> x =
```

So far so good. But not quite there yet. Now there is the extra generic parameter, but it's not clear whether, and how, it is related to the parameter `x`. The type of `x` should be `Result<_,_>`, that much is clear from the implementation. But should it be `Result<`a, string>`or`Resulta>? Or maybe even `Result<'a, 'a>`? There is no way to tell!

So, let's help the compiler out some more and specify the type of `x`:

```
let endFlow<`a, 'T when 'T :> exn> (x : Result<'a, string>) =
```

Now the signature is exactly what you want.

However, even after fixing it like this, it still won't work the way you expect. You see, the expression `exn e :?> 'T` doesn't do what you think it does.

The expression `exn e` will create an object of type `exn` (aka `System.Exception`), which you then attempt to cast to some unknown type `'T`. The underlying object is definitely *not* of type `'T` (we already know it's of type `exn`), so the result of such cast will be `null`. Not quite what you expected, is it?

Come to think of it, how do you even know that an exception of type `'T` can be constructed out of a string at all?

If you really want to throw an exception of a caller-defined type, you have to provide a way to construct such exception - i.e. provide a constructor function:

```
let endFlow<'a, 'T when 'T :> exn> (mkExn : string -> 'T)  (x : Result<'a, string>) = 
    match x with
    | Ok o -> ()
    | Error (e: string) ->
       mkExn e |> raise
```

Usage:

```
let r : Result<int, string> = ...
r |> endFlow exn      // throws System.Exception
r |> endFlow System.InvalidOperationException    // throws System.InvalidOperationException
```